# Clearing Cache While Running a Program

Tags: testing, caching, pentaho-data-integration

This may be a question for superuser, and if so, I'm happy to delete my question and post there.

What are the negative effects of clearing a software program cache while that program is running? Will I get bad/inaccurate data results (depending on the program of course)? Is it safe to do so while the program is running?